# Can this work - Google Cloud Endpoints as API Management layer and Istio as Service Mesh on Kubernetes (GKE)

Tags: kubernetes, cloud, google-cloud-endpoints, google-kubernetes-engine, istio

We would like to use Kubernetes for Microservices and Google Cloud Endpoints as API Management layer.

If I understand well, to have Google Cloud Endpoints functionality we need to have a sidecar or proxy for the real microservice. (image: gcr.io/endpoints-release/endpoints-runtime:1)

So if we were to use Istio as service Mesh technology how will Envoy proxy work along with Google Cloud Endpoint? Will it actually proxy even the google cloud endpoint relevant container?

Or is this a bad strategy?